# New guidelines for reviewing suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review

I was back reviewing suggested edits after a long time when I noticed that the reasons provided for rejecting a edit have all changed.

So are there some new guidelines as to what I am supposed to do?

Especially for edits that would prior be rejected as minor because they only changed tags and nothing else.

Comment: Valid tag edits were never too minor! Anyway, the new idea is that no edit is too minor.

Comment: @terdon Sure, but many user use it as a cheap way of earning some rep points, by changing a single tag when it's not really necessary.

Comment: Well, yes but if it's a correct tag then the edit is fine. If not, it should be rejected as a bad edit, not as too minor. Anyway, I'm nitpicking, sorry. You can find the official stance here: [Approve as too minor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149722)

Answer (score 4):

This was implemented network-wide. The rationale is explained in this meta.SE question:

[Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149722/203101)

Briefly:

> If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!

So, improve the edit if it can be improved and reject if it doesn't help at all.